# How to create a Mercurial repository on a remote IIS web server

Tags: iis, mercurial

I have a Windows Server 2003 running Mercurial's hgwebdir.cgi to serve repositories. Push/Pull etc is working as expected for existing repositories.

Currently I'm using remote desktop If I need a new repository on the server.

Is there a better way to do it? Command line, web interface, cgi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mercurial by itself only allows for the creation of repositories locally or over ssh.  For http you need to either log in to the server via command line and `hg init` or via RDP and do essentially the same.

It is, however, very easy to create a small CGI script that will create new remote repositories over HTTP.  Here's one I built that works on unix and is likely easily adapted to windows:

http://ry4an.org/unblog/UnBlog/2009-09-17

Answer (score 1):

currently , running hg init where you want the repository is the way to do it, any other way would require hgwebdir to implement some kind of security better left to other/better/more os specific tools. It's not that much of a leap to imagine that the HG devs rather focus on the versioning of files than reinventing the wheel with security, at least right now.